# Trying to fill an array position with a value and then increment it

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to do a console menu and this is the first option where you enter a brand of whiskey. I don't want any null values so the index variable is 2 when the while loop starts. I've tried different versions of this but can't make it work.

```
while (meny != 6) {
   meny = scnObj.nextInt();
   switch (meny) {
      case 0:
         if (whiskey[index] == whiskey[index]) {
            whiskey = Arrays.copyOf(whiskey, whiskey.length + 1);
            index++;
         }

         System.out.println("\nSkriv namnet på whiskeyn du vill lägga till: \n");
         whiskey[index] = scnObj.nextLine();

         break;
```

Comment: I think we need more information. Though `if (whiskey[index] == whiskey[index])` seems suspicious...

Comment: Since you're using `whiskey[index] = scnObj.nextLine();`, we can assume that `whiskey` is an array of `String`s, which means that `whiskey[index] == whiskey[index]` is wrong and should be `whiskey[index].equals(whiskey[index])`, however, that doesn't make sense, because it'll always be `true`

Comment: `whiskey[index] == whiskey[index]` > like: `water == water ??!!!`   , also whats inside meny ? can we see that array format to know more were is the problem .